# Write a LambdaExpression that is reevaluated between DbContext recreations?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, entity-framework-core

I'm attempting to use the [Global Query Filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters) in EF Core 3.0. Overall, they're working fairly well, but with one minor hiccup. I've been attempting to set up multitenancy in a manner similar to the guide [here](https://stackify.com/writing-multitenant-asp-net-core-applications/). My use-case is a bit different as the tenant is derived from a query string parameter (or header), and it's subject to change between requests.

If I define an interface `IOrganizationEntity` with a member called `Organization`. I'm able to define the global query filters using the statement `entity.HasQueryFilter<IOrganizationEntity>(o => o.Organization == OrganizationId)`, and this works as expected. However, I'm trying to avoid placing an `Organization` property on my entity POCO, and instead I'm trying to use something similar to:

```cs
private Guid OrganizationId => HasOrganization ? _organizationService.GetCurrentOrganizationId() : Guid.Empty;

private void ConfigureOrganizationFilter(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().Where(x =>
        typeof(IOrganizationEntity).IsAssignableFrom(x.ClrType)))
    {
        entity.AddProperty(nameof(Organization), typeof(Guid));
        // Note, AddQueryFilter is an extension method that allows us to add multiple
        // query filters to a single type of entity.
        entity.AddQueryFilter(IsOrganizationRestricted(entity.ClrType));
    }
}

private LambdaExpression IsOrganizationRestricted(Type type)
{
    var propertyMethod = typeof(EF).GetMethod(nameof(EF.Property),
        BindingFlags.Static |
        BindingFlags.Public)?.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Guid));

    if (propertyMethod == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Object does not appear to be valid for operation.");

    var param = Expression.Parameter(type, "it");
    var prop = Expression.Call(propertyMethod, param, Expression.Constant(nameof(Organization)));
    var condition = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, prop, Expression.Constant(OrganizationId));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(condition, param);

    return lambda;
}
```

However, when I use the above code, the filtering works as intended on the first run, but it fails on subsequent runs where the `OrganizationId` has changed. I'm fairly new to writing `Expression` functions explicitly, so I'm not sure what needs to happen to force a reevaluation of the OrganizationId

Comment: Write out what the expression would have looked like if done manually and use that as your template to build the expression dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be reevaluated, the filter expression must access property/field/method of the db context derived class.

Assuming the code in question is located inside your db context derived class, i.e. `OrganizationId` is a property of that class, the problem is that

```
Expression.Constant(OrganizationId)
```

evaluates it at the time you build the filter and binds a *constant* value into filter expression.

Instead, you should bind `OrganizationId` property accessor expression (i.e. `Expression.Property`) like this:

```
// this.OrganizationId
Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(this), nameof(OrganizationId))
```